# DeviceCheck Without A Server

Tags: swift, xcode, devicecheck

I am trying to implement DeviceCheck for my app. I am new to coding and do not have the resources to build a server to be an intermediary between the client and Apple's servers. Is it possible to just query for and update the DeviceCheck bits just on the device?

I have tried converting some DeviceCheck tutorial's server code to swift but have not had any luck. Can anyone help me wit this?

Comment: Why not use a free tier AWS instance or something along those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to have this problem too, but I decided to use a $0 non-consumable purchase since that will be recorded in the Apple receipt file. Depending on what you need it for, this could be the simplest way to do something similar to DeviceCheck without adding your own server component